# PostgreSQL 'Deferrable Delete' still hits constraint on Delete

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions, cascade

I want to delete rows from two tables which have a dependence upon each other through a set of deferrable constraints. To simplify this post, I've mocked up a simple DB schema.

I'm hoping to remove entries from some table, 'delete_from_me', inside a SQL transaction/DB Patch. The catch is, I want to delete based on a select from a second table 'constraining_table' before I loose the link itself.

Here's a description of the two tables:

```
tab-quarantine=> \d delete_from_me
       Table "public.delete_from_me"
  Column   |       Type        | Modifiers 
-----------+-------------------+-----------
 id        | character varying | not null
 extension | character varying | not null
Indexes:
    "delete_from_me_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)

tab-quarantine=> \d constraining_table 
   Table "public.constraining_table"
 Column |       Type        | Modifiers 
--------+-------------------+-----------
 image  | character varying | not null
 type   | character varying | not null
Foreign-key constraints:
    "constraining_table_image_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (image) REFERENCES delete_from_me(id)
         ON UPDATE CASCADE
         ON DELETE RESTRICT DEFERRABLE
```

Here's some sample data I just blatted in there:

```
tab-quarantine=> SELECT * FROM delete_from_me;
     id     | extension 
------------+-----------
 12345abcde | png
(1 row)

tab-quarantine=> SELECT * FROM constraining_table;
   image    |   type   
------------+----------
 12345abcde | select_me
(1 row)
```

And here goes my transaction:

```
BEGIN;
\set ON_ERROR_STOP 1
SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED;
DELETE FROM delete_from_me WHERE id IN (
    SELECT image FROM constraining_table WHERE type = 'select_me'
);
DELETE FROM constraining_table WHERE type = 'select_me';
COMMIT;
```

This transaction fails. When I step through and do this manually, I'm presented with the following error message:

```
ERROR:  update or delete on table "delete_from_me" violates foreign key constraint "constraining_table_image_fkey" on table "constraining_table"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(12345abcde) is still referenced from table "constraining_table".
```

This seems like a good candidate for a temporary table, however I'd like to know *why* it is that I can't delete in this order given the constraints should not be effective till the end of the transaction?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `ON DELETE NO ACTION DEFERRABLE` instead of `ON DELETE RESTRICT DEFERRABLE`.  Using `RESTRICT` instead of `NO ACTION` forces the constraint to be non-deferrable, regardless of whether you apply the `DEFERRABLE` modifier.

This is in the fine print of the [manual page for `CREATE TABLE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-createtable.html):

> Referential actions other than the NO ACTION  check cannot be deferred, even if the constraint is declared deferrable.

Obviously, the above caveat includes `RESTRICT`.

Following shortly after this sentence are the definitions of `NO ACTION` and `RESTRICT`:

> NO ACTION
>
> Produce an error indicating that the deletion or update would create a foreign key constraint violation. If the constraint is deferred, this error will be produced at constraint check time if there still exist any referencing rows. This is the default action.
>
> RESTRICT
>
> Produce an error indicating that the deletion or update would create a foreign key constraint violation. This is the same as NO ACTION except that the check is not deferrable.

As you can see, `NO ACTION` will behave identically to `RESTRICT`, except `NO ACTION` is deferrable.  This is why I recommended it -- I think it's just what you're asking for.